# BrowserModule has already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor from a lazy loaded module

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, lazy-loading, node-modules, angular9

Browser Animation module is already imported from our own module, when importing our module within our shared module and after that lazy loading the child module is causing the below error

Console Error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: BrowserModule has already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor from a lazy loaded module, import CommonModule instead.
Error: BrowserModule has already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor from a lazy loaded module, import CommonModule instead.
    at new BrowserModule (platform-browser.js:2572)
    at Object.BrowserModule_Factory [as factory] (platform-browser.js:2595)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (core.js:17206)
    at R3Injector.get (core.js:16956)
    at core.js:17002
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at R3Injector._resolveInjectorDefTypes (core.js:16998)
    at new NgModuleRef$1 (core.js:36329)
    at NgModuleFactory$1.create (core.js:36428)
    at MapSubscriber.project (router.js:6507)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:798)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:750)
    at zone-evergreen.js:860
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:41645)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:398)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:167)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:569)
```

Comment: What error? You didn't include one

Comment: Please attach the error

Comment: Attached console error log

Comment: Please attach your code as a [mre]. See also [ask]